# ¿Como desplegar varias opciones dentro de un menu en cosola en java?

Tags: java, poo, menú, java-util-scanner

Mi pregunta es como realizar una especie de menu dentro de otro menu. Por ejemplo, yo despliego en mi codigo 4 opciones a elegir, en una de ellas si es elegida precisaria que se despliegue tambien varias opciones para elegir. Seria como un menu anidado. A continuacion les dejo mi codigo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Menu{

public static void main(String[] args){

    int opciones;
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    Opcion1 op1=null;
    Opcion2 op2=null;
    Opcion3 op3=null;
    Opcion4 op4=null;

    System.out.println("Menu por consola");
    System.out.println("1.- Registrar nuevo empleado");
    System.out.println("2.- Obtener datos de contacto de un empleado");
    System.out.println("3.- Listar todos los empleados que cumplan anios en cierta fecha");
    System.out.println("4.- Obtener el presupuesto total");
    System.out.println("Ingrese la accion a realizar: ") //Pretendo que el usuario escriba el numero de  opcion
    opciones=leer.nexInt();

    switch(opciones) {
    case 1: 
    op1=new Opcion1();
    op1.registrarNuevoEmpleado();
    break;

    case 2:
    op2=new Opcion2();
    op2.obtenerDatos();
    String variable = op1.variableOpcion1;
    break;

    case 3: 
    op3=new Opcion3();
    op3.listarEmpleadosCumpleaños();
    break;

    case 4: 
    op4=new Opcion4();
    op4.presupuestoPorArea();
    break;

    default:
    System.out.println ("Numero no valido"); 
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que hacer uso de un bucle (recomiendo el do-while):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Editor {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean sal = false;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
        System.out.println("Ingresa A para saludarte, y B para despedirme: ");
        switch(in.next()){
            case "A":
                System.out.println("Hola");
                break;
            case "B":
                System.out.println("Adios");
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("¿Salir de este bucle?");
        if(in.next().equals("Si")) sal=true;
        else sal=false;
    }while(!sal);
}   
}
```

Este pequeño ejemplo, es un bucle do-while, en el que el bucle se ejecutara hasta que el usuario desee salir (ingresando cualquier caracter o cadena que sea distinto de "Si").

- El bucle inicia dando una instruccion.
- Se inicia un switch, en el que se evalua los valores capturados por el teclado (Scanner). Si el usuario ingreso A, entonces se imprimira por consola "Hola". Si el usuario ingresa B, entonces se imprime por consola "Adios". (Si se ingresara otra cosa distinta de A o B, simplemente no hace nada y prosigue con la siguiente parte y ultima)
- Ahora en la ultima parte del bucle, el programa le pregunta al usuario si desea salir del bucle. Para continuar, el usuario debera ingresar "Si" (al apretar Si, simplemente a nuestra variable booleana se le asigna "true" para que la condicion del bucle no se cumpla y se rompa).

La condicion es que el bucle seguira corriendo mientras que nuestra variable booleana sea distinta a true.

Ya con esto puedes hacer menus desde consola

Comment: ¿Y donde esta el submenu que es lo que pide el usuario?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pides es sencillo. Solo tienes que crear un nuevo menú dentro del case del `switch`. Tal como el menú principal que tienes.

```
class Menu{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ...

        System.out.println("Menu por consola");
        System.out.println("1.- Registrar nuevo empleado");
        System.out.println("2.- Obtener datos de contacto de un empleado");
        System.out.println("3.- Listar todos los empleados que cumplan anios en cierta fecha");
        System.out.println("4.- Obtener el presupuesto total");
        System.out.println("Ingrese la accion a realizar: ") //Pretendo que el usuario escriba el numero de  opcion
        opciones=leer.nexInt();
        leer.nexLine();

        switch(opciones) {
        case 1: 

        System.out.println("Menu registrar nuevo empleado");
        System.out.println("1.- Opcion 1");
        System.out.println("2.- Opcion 2");
        System.out.println("3.- Opcion 3");
        System.out.println("4.- Opcion 4");

        int opciones2 = leer.nexInt();
        leer.nexLine();

        switch (opciones2) {

            case 1:
                // codigo
                break;

            case 2:
                // codigo
                break;

            case 3:
                // codigo
                break;

            case 4:
                // codigo
                break;

        }

        op1=new Opcion1();
        op1.registrarNuevoEmpleado();
        break;

        case 2:
            menu3();
            ...
            break;

        ...
    }

    public static void menu3() {

        System.out.println("Menu registrar nuevo empleado");
        System.out.println("1.- Opcion 1");
        System.out.println("2.- Opcion 2");
        System.out.println("3.- Opcion 3");
        System.out.println("4.- Opcion 4");

        int opciones2 = leer.nexInt();
        leer.nexLine();

        switch (opciones2) {

            case 1:
                // codigo
                break;

            case 2:
                // codigo
                break;

            case 3:
                // codigo
                break;

            case 4:
                // codigo
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Aunque te recomiendo que crees el menú dentro de un método y lo llames dentro del `case`. Como se hace en el segundo `case` del `switch` principal.